# Upload an Image to a RESTful API

Tags: ios, json, swift

hello I am successfully posting data into server but this time I want to upload an image to server. I am using this function to post the data without image

```
static func postToServer(url:String,params:Dictionary<String,NSObject>,image:String?, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, String?) -> Void ) -> NSURLSessionTask {


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)


        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    if(params["data"] != "get"){
        do {

            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)

            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("dataString is  \(dataString)")

            request.HTTPBody = data//try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)


        } catch {
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print("error is \(error)")
            //return
        }

    }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error
            guard error == nil else { return }

            //print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
             completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(strData!)")
           //print("Body: \(strData!)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
              print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(jsonStr!)")

                // return or throw?
                return
            }


            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

                completionHandler(parseJSON,nil)
                //let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                //print("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(jsonStr!)")
            }

        }

        task.resume()
        return task
    }
```

Now as I have to send an image now also I think I have to do this

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
var base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)

var params = ["image":[ "content_type": "image/jpeg", "filename":"test.jpg", "file_data": base64String]]
```

now the problem is how can I add these params in the above params variable. I mean right now the format of my params is like this

```
{
  "email" : "hello",
  "password" : "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just add them to the params you already have, like this?

```
var params = ["email":"hello", "password":"hello"]

params["image"] = ["content_type": "image/jpeg", "filename":"test.jpg", "file_data": base64String]
```

Comment: yes.. what If I do this

params = [
            "email": self.email,
            "password": self.password,
            "first_name": self.firstName,
            "last_name": self.lastName
            
        ]

params["image"] = [ "content_type": "image/jpeg", "filename":"test.jpg", "file_data": base64String]

will it work ?

Comment: Yup, same thing but other way around. Should work fine. I'll update my answer.